# Setting a folder's Icon

Tags: c#, icons, directory

Basically what I want to do is make a folder disappear from my computer (and not simply hide it).
But I can't find a normal way (less than a 100 lines) to just assign any icon to any folder.
Is there a way?

PS: I can extract the blank icon and copy it with my install folder, thats not a problem =)

Comment: This looks like a very roundabout way to hide a folder. Why don't you set the folder's `hidden` flag and configure Explorer not to show hidden files instead?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, I don't think rendering a blank icon will actually help you make a folder "disappear".

Even if you write a [shell icon handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122.aspx) that returns a blank icon for your folder, it won't prevent that folder from being interacted with. It will still be selectable in Explorer, and its name will be visible. The command line interface will, of course, completely ignore the icon.

If you want to hide the folder from your end users, you should give it the appropriate permissions, or simply mark it as hidden in the file system. In both cases, it means accepting that power users and system administrators can see it.